# Publish app containing virtual directory to Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

I have an app that's structured like this:

```
app\ <-- not exposed through IIS
 -> Config\ <-- Contains config for IIS application
 -> Shared\ <-- Contains binaries for IIS application
 -> Transform\ <-- Config, etc
 -> Web\  <--- IIS application directory
```

I don't want to have to restructure the entire thing so that everything outside Web\ is contained within it and referenced that way. However, I can't get visual studio to publish to my app service in such a way that Web\ is the IIS application directory and everything else is published above it.

I've tried a lot of different ways to set the Virtual Applications and Directories for the app service but none of them are working. How can I publish to a parent of the IIS application directory?

Comment: other than web\ folders are class libraries?, and your web aplication is inside web\?

Comment: Could you show me more detail info about the structure? Is the "app" is a webapp and the "web" is also webapp. If so, why don't your publish twice so that you could clearly specified which virtual directory.

Comment: @programtreasures That is correct.

Comment: @JoeyCai app\ should not be exposed through IIS. I updated my question in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with two applications: one for `app/` and one for `app/Web/`. Publishing to `app/` is now working even though I could swear it was producing unintended consequences when I first tried it. Here is my msdeploy command, a good bit of which came from David Ebbo's [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simple-azure-websites-deployment/):

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="$projectDir\Package" -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site",computerName="https://myAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site",userName=$user,password=$password.Trim(),AuthType=Basic
```